# Global threshold for emgucv in csharp

Tags: c#, opencv, ocr, tesseract, emgucv

Well I am new to OCR and Emgucv and here it goes. I am having colored ID card that I want to process through tesseract ocr to get details. I have converted color image to gray scale and I have successfully converted to binary image and passed the same to  tesseract and worked properly though i have to filter junk data from text received.

Now my issue is I am expecting different kind of images having such as contrast, lighting conditioning  from users. I want to know if something is available  which I can do to get global threshold to get binary image. I already played with adaptivethreshold, Otsu but did not worked for me.

What I am assuming is images are matrix of pixels so is their anyway to write some function which will work on any image? I am not able to figureout where should I start with.

I am working on csharp and using tesseract for ocr. I have used following code.

```
double th = CvInvoke.Threshold(source, source2, 0, 255, ThresholdType.Otsu);
CvInvoke.Threshold(source, source, th/2, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);
```

Sample Image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JleRx.jpg

Please suggest example in csharp to find global threshold.

I am doing following steps for OCR.

- Gray scale
- Threshold
- Tesseract

Additionally Please let me know whether I am doing expected algorithm for OCR or I am missing something? Also please suggest  what should i do to improve ocr accuracy? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: +1 Your questions are improving a lot, good job! In your application you have the good fortune of knowing the colour of the text you are searching for. I would suggest converting the image to HSV, then filtering on Hue to extract just the text. You also know the location of the text. When I have some time soon, I'll work on an example for you.

Comment: Thanks! I will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Canny Edge detection.
[Emgu CV Canny](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/fc9004a0-ce7f-2b0b-a090-ad67a7f97fea.htm)

It should help your accuracy. It finds edges by their local differences, not by the brightness/contrast of the whole image.

Comment: OK. So My steps should be Canny edge detector => gray scale  => thresh holding  => OCR. Am I correct?

Comment: I would go with gray scale => canny edge => OCR. Test if it will work for you. Depends on the images you want to use.

Comment: Well I have tested same set of images by doing gray  scale => canny edge => OCR. and gray  scale  => OCR . I have observed that gray  scale  => OCR  has better accuracy.